# do not continue when exception

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I would like use "try except" statement, but in two function. I caught an exception in function, but function2 does anyway. How can i stop it until there is an exception

i want to transfer it to a window application. If the file does not load, I want to display an information window. I only want the program to go on (function2) when the file loads

```py
class Files:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "fle.txt"
    def function(self):
        try:
            self.f = open(self.name, 'rb')
        except OSError:
            print("Problem!!!")
            
    def function2(self):
        print(self.f.read())
        
def main():
    file=Files()
    file.function()
    file.function2()
```

Comment: after the print("Problem") just exit()

Comment: In function2 you need to check for the existence of self.f and its value. That answers your question but there are significant issues with the way you're doing this. I also think someone's missed the irony in @tomgalpin's comment

Comment: @AlbertWinestein yeah it's ironic, but he could very well be serious and that's how we end up in those situations "Problem, what problem?!"

Comment: I'd say change your logic. You're catching an error just to print "problem" and continue execution like the exception never happened. Except the exception at the point in code where you no longer rely on it not happening.

Comment: so, here is just print(), but in my app i try display windows with information,

Answer (score 3):

Don't catch an exception unless you **actually** know how to handle it.

```
class Files:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "fle.txt"
        self.f = None
    def function(self):
        self.f = open(self.name, 'rb')
            
    def function2(self):
        if self.f is None:
            raise Exception("File not initialized!") #Example
            #return #just if you don't throw or exit
        print(self.f.read())

        
def main():
    file=Files()
    try:
        file.function()
    except OSError:
        print("Problem!!!")
    else:
        file.function2()

main()
```

Comment: Thank you! It work very well. I thought that if I split the program into classes and objects, catching exceptions should also be in the appropriate class, not the main function

Comment: Note how this doesn't close the file. (The code in the question doesn't either.)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your function calls in a higher level try/except.

Of course, you would never write anything like this because it's so inflexible. This answer does not condone the OP's approach but suggests how that could be made to work.

```
class Files:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'fle.txt'

    def function_1(self):
        self.fd = open(self.name)

    def function_2(self):
        print(self.fd.read())

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.fd.close()
        except Exception:
            pass


file = Files()

try:
    file.function_1()
    file.function_2()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

So we don't do any exception handling (except in __del__ where we ignore any issues) within the class functions but allow all/any exceptions to propagate to the caller. Here we want to call two class functions but we wrap them in the same try/except block.

If function_1 raises an exception, function_2 won't be called.

**del** added to show how one *could* clean up but it's not the way this should be handled

Answer (score -1):

@tomgalpin is right you could just exit right there after the problem
But this being a class maybe you want to print the error and pass back no data?

Here's one way to look at that with Tom's included sys exit (commented out)

Also be sure if you keep your code to close the file handler. Calling open on a file without .close() can leave file handlers open and cause problems for you if your class were to continue on after.

```
class Files:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "fle.txt"
        # Empty string in data if no data
        self.data = ""
    def function(self):
        try:
            #self.f = open(self.name, 'rb')
            with open(self.name, 'rb') as f:
                self.data = f.read()

        except OSError as err:
            print("Problem!!!", err)
            # You could exit
            # sys.exit()
        # But you could also return an empty string, 
        #  which is "falsy", regardless of what happens
        finally:
            return self.data
            
    def function2(self):
        print(f"Data 3 {self.data}")
        
def main():
    file=Files()
    # You could print this, or use it to get the data
    print("Data 1", file.function())
    data = file.function()
    print(f"Data 2 {data}")
    # this now also shows the data
    file.function2()
```

Comment: Good job using `open`, but this is messy, hides the problem and basically just kicks the can down the road (instead of picking it up and throwing it into the nearest bin :) ). Every single piece of code now needs to check if `self.data` is an empty string (and can't distinguish between an error reading the file and a case where the file is just empty). Even just re-raising the exception will do wonders

Comment: that's exactly what i wanted to do as this is just an example and i want to transfer it to a window application. If the file does not load, I want to display an information window. I only want the program to go on (function2) when the file loads

Comment: @czerwonyjakcegla so use `try-except-else`. The `else` block only executes if **no** exception was raised.

Comment: And in my previous comment I meant to write "good job using **`with`**", not `open` :)

Comment: @DeepSpace is partially correct. The problem here is that one would have to use that in the main program and allow the exception from *function()* to be raised to its caller

Answer (score -1):

Use the variable that is usually `True` but becomes `False` if function fails

### Example

```
class Files:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "file.txt"
        self.Continue=True
        self.data = ""
    def function(self):
        try:
            #self.f = open(self.name, 'rb')
            with open(self.name, 'rb') as f:
                self.data = f.read()

        except OSError as err:
            print("Problem!!!", err)
            self.Continue=False
            return False
        finally:
            return self.data
            
    def function2(self):
        if self.Continue:
            print(self.data)
        else:
            #Code if function failed
        
def main():
    file=Files()
    file.function()
    file.function2()
```

Comment: If you need a flag like that, that should tell you you're doing something wrong.

Comment: What happened ?